# Calculate the probability density function of a segment' length

Tags: probability

There is a circle, with radius $R_0$, is centered on the origin. Choose a uniformly random point $(x,y)$ on the circle.

Q1: Calculate the PDF $f(x,y)$

Q2: Calculate the PDF $f(l)$ of the length of the segment connecting $(x,y)$ and $(-R_0, 0)$

The first question is obviously to the uniform distribution:
$$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi R_0}$$ $$x^2+y^2 = R_0^2$$

Please help me to calculate the second PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\theta$ be the angle between axis x and the segment, so $\theta$ follows $R(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, then the segment Y comes to $2R\cos(\theta)$.

$P(Y\le y)=P(2R\cos(\theta)\le y)=P(cos(\theta)\le y/2R)$

$=P(\pi/2 \ge \theta \ge \arccos(y/2R))+P(-\pi/2 \le \theta \le -\arccos(y/2R))$

$=\int_{\arccos(y/2R)}^{\pi/2}1/\pi d\theta+\int_{-\pi/2}^{-\arccos(y/2R)}1/\pi d\theta$

Differentiate it by $y$ comes

$l(y)=\frac{2}{\pi \sqrt{4R^2-y^2}}, y\in[0,2R]$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that if $L$ is the random distance between $(x,y)$ and $(-R_0,0)$, then 
$$
L=\sqrt{(x+R_0)^2+y^2}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+2R_0x+R_0^2}=\sqrt{2R_0^2+2R_0x}=\sqrt{2R_0(R_0+x)}.
$$
So,
$$
P(L=\ell)=P(L^2=\ell^2)=P(2R_0(R_0+x)=\ell^2).
$$
The equation $2R_0(R_0+x)=\ell^2$ has a unique solution for $x$, as long as $\ell$ is in the proper range; and given $x$, there are either $1$ or $2$ values of $y$ so that $(x,y)$ is actually a point on the circle.